# Definition of t2g orbitals in CFT

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, crystal-field-theory

My textbook defines $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ orbitals as

> $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ stands for a set of three orbitals which are asymmetric with respect to $C_2$ axes, perpendicular to the highest $C_n$ axes, but which is symmetric in sign through the centre of inversion.

I know that “$\mathrm{t}$” is a randomly chosen letter as suggested by M. Farooq, “$\mathrm{g}$” comes from gerade (MOT), that's what  the last line says. Though “$2$” in subscript must have come from $C_2$, but I didn't get the meaning of

> …which are asymmetric with respect to $C_2$ axes, perpendicular to the highest $C_n$ axes.

Please explain what does this line conveys.

Comment: I have checked the original literature, t or T, does not stand for three or triplet. It was a randomly chosen letter. You are right g is for *gerade*. In original works, the letter F was used alphabetically, A,B,E, F as symmetry labels.

Comment: Dos this answer your question: [What are t2g and eg in CFT?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/17284)

Comment: @andselisk But this post does not include the above definition or it's meaning. Wasn't the meaning of "t, e, g" explained in broader essence?

Comment: @M.Farooq what is the original literature for this? I had always assumed the symmetry labels had some German connection.

Comment: Tyberius, actually not. I was planning to write a short historical article. Except for g and u I could not authenticate any other German meaning. The rest are mostly myths including $Entartet$ for degenerate.